# Loading Spinner Image too fast at start of Function

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a function that displays contents of a posts when clicked on. I want the loading spinner to display and delay for few sections before the post content appears. The issue here is when I click on each post, the spinner appears for maybe 1ms and in some cases it disappears long before the content appears.

```
function showPost(id) {
    setTimeout(function() {$('#loader').show();},1);
    $('#pcontent').empty();
    $.getJSON('http://howtodeployit.com/category/daily-devotion/?json=get_post&post_id=' + id + '&callback=?', function(data) {
    var $postcon = $('<div/>').append([$("<h3>", {html: data.post.title}),$("<p>", {html: data.post.content})]);
        $postcon.appendTo('#pcontent');
    });
}
```

Spinner HTML:

```
<div id='loader'><img src="css/images/loader.gif"/></div>
```

Comment: does the #loader element reside in the #pcontent element. Is it a child of that ele? If so, you empty it out right after you set the spinner to show.

Comment: Why do you have to call the settimeout function?

Comment: the timeout bit is commented out since I was just testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function showPost(id) {

    $('#loader').show();
    $('#pcontent').empty();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://howtodeployit.com/category/daily-devotion/?json=get_post&post_id=' + id + '&callback=?',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var $postcon = $('<div/>').append([$("<h3>", {
                html: data.post.title
            }), $("<p>", {
                html: data.post.content
            })]);
            $postcon.appendTo('#pcontent');
            $('#loader').hide();
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: I didn't plan using an ajax call to load post content but since you have suggested it here, then I have no choice to use it. I try with this approach first:

beforeSend: function() { $('#loader').show(); },
            complete: function() { $('#loader').hide(); },

Comment: Using yours, the post content not appearing. Console loggged the 'data' but no content

Comment: OK the only thing missing from your suggestion is 'dataType: "json"'

Answer (score 0):

gif image always behave differently on every device..basically it depends upon device's processing speed. so better option is to use image sprites and animate it with javascript.. 
In your case at page load there is nothing processing..but as page starts to load device's processor cant handle the load and as a result your gif image gets slower

Answer (score 0):

It seems from your last commented line that you are using a timeout to hide the loader. Instead You should handle the hiding inside the callback function of your ajax request, so that loader hides after request is completed, not after a fixed amount of time:

```
function showPost(id) {
    $('#loader').show();
    $('#pcontent').empty();
    $.getJSON('http://howtodeployit.com/category/daily-devotion/?json=get_post&post_id=' + id + '&callback=?', function(data) {
        $('#loader').hide();
        var $postcon = $('<div/>').append([$("<h3>", {html: data.post.title}),$("<p>", {html: data.post.content})]);
        $postcon.appendTo('#pcontent');
    });
}
```

Comment: I have tried your approach also. I am not saying the spinner does not show but some times, it shows too fast and few milliseconds delay before the actual post shows

Comment: Also make sure that loader is not a child of `pcontent`, otherwise you'll be deleting the loader as soon as `showPost` is called.